# Disable options based on currently selected option with Material UI Autocomplete component

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I am creating an Autocomplete element using Material UI, React Hook Form, and Yup that allows a user to choose multiple inputs for the days of the week.

If a user chooses the "Every day" option, I want to disable being able to choose Sunday, Monday, Tues... etc. How would I do that using getOptionDisabled?

Here is my current code...

```
const daysOfWeekSuggestions = [
    {label: "Every day"},
    {label: "Sunday"},
    {label: "Monday"},
    {label: "Tuesday"},
    {label: "Wednesday"},
    {label: "Thursday"},
    {label: "Friday"},
    {label: "Saturday"}
];

<Autocomplete
    disableClearable
    disablePortal
    filterSelectedOptions
    multiple
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
    id="days-autocomplete"
    options={daysOfWeekSuggestions}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField
        required
        error={errors.daysOfWeek ? true : false}
        id="daysOfWeek"
        label="Days of the week"
        name="daysOfWeek"
        type="search"
        {...params}
        {...register("daysOfWeek")}
    />}
/>
```

Comment: Are you saving the value from the component in state? if so could you also include that

Comment: And what version of material ui are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is use the `getOptionDisabled` prop and then check to see if the user has already selected Every Day. Im guessing you are saving it into state similar to how I am using it here so you can then just use the `.some` function to see if the Every day object is in the values array.

```js
const daysOfWeekSuggestions = [
  { label: "Every day" },
  { label: "Sunday" },
  { label: "Monday" },
  { label: "Tuesday" },
  { label: "Wednesday" },
  { label: "Thursday" },
  { label: "Friday" },
  { label: "Saturday" }
];

export default function DaysOfTheWeekSelect() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([]);

  const handleOnChange = (e, value) => {
    setValue(value);
  };

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      disableClearable
      disablePortal
      multiple
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
      id="days-autocomplete"
      onChange={handleOnChange}
      options={daysOfWeekSuggestions}
      getOptionDisabled={(option) => {
        if (value.some((day) => day.label === "Every day")) {
          return true;
        }
        if (value.some((day) => day.label === option.label)) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }}
      value={value}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          required
          error={errors.daysOfWeek ? true : false}
          id="daysOfWeek"
          label="Days of the week"
          name="daysOfWeek"
          type="search"
          {...params}
          {...register("daysOfWeek")}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

I also made it that if you have already selected a value then it would be disabled as well. Just seems a little bit better than just filtering out the selected values

Comment: you return true in both case of your conditions in getOptionDisabled what's the point to add condition if in both case you return true mate ? none.

Comment: @BackSlashHaine I was missing the final return false in there so good catch. But without it then it still would would of still worked because if none of those conditions matched then it would of returned undefined.

Comment: also `.some` is already returning a boolean depending of the completion of the condition so `return true` is useless too, working code yeah but bad code still.

Comment: there are probably a million different ways to do those if statements. You could easily simplify it down to 1 line but then its hard to read and separating it out into 2 if statements makes it easier to help the question asker understand. I wouldn't say bad code, just the long way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need more than just getOptionDisabled option.
I have done similar thing in my prev app, for that you need to add one more property called disabled to each option and onChange to Every day, manually disable remaining options.

You can check working demo here - https://codesandbox.io/s/disable-mui-autocomplete-options-on-condition-gurzb

Comment: This worked, thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you so much again for your help! I have implemented your solution into this component and it worked great. However, now I am getting stuck on the validation aspect. Can you check out my other question/code sandbox? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70140006/why-isnt-my-forms-button-turning-on-when-the-form-is-supplied-valid-input-data

Answer (score 0):

Try using the isOptionEqualToValue instead

```
<Autocomplete
     ...
     isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
     ...
/>
```

supply the identifying property, in this case 'id'