# Why isn't my form's button turning on when the form is supplied valid input data? (Includes code sandbox)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, react-hook-form, yup

I am using Material UI's Autocomplete multiple TextField, React Hook Form, and Yup to validate the form inputs.

The following form asks a user to input days of the week. If they input "every day", the other options are disabled/if a user inputs any day(s), the "every day" option is disabled.

On my form, I have set it so that if the form input is not valid, the submit button will remain disabled. I am trying to use the following Yup validation schema to do this, but it is not working...

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
daysOfWeek: Yup.array()
    .of(
        Yup.object().shape({
            label: Yup.string(),
            disabled: Yup.boolean(),
        })
    )
    .min(1, "Days of the week are required")
});
```

Can you please check out my code sandbox and see what may be going wrong? Thanks so much in advance!

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-cookies-n5iyl

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out!

Updated code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-cookies-n5iyl?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).